# NextJS 13 with Prisma and SQL Server deployed to Azure Web Service

Tags: sql-server, azure, next.js, connection, prisma

I have an issue with Prisma configuration in my application, I was following Kyles from WDS tutorial on YouTube where he is using Prisma with NodeJS 13 and SQLite.

[Tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgayZAuTgwM&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified)

I used SQL Server database and its all working as expected locally but when published to Azure I am getting errors, please see the detailed log from Azure portal logging option:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSQet.png)

This is prisma.schema

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

// more info about prefixed connection strings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal
datasource db {
  provider = "sqlserver"
  url      = env("SQLCONNSTR_DATABASE_URL")
}

model Todos {
  id        String   @id @default(uuid())
  title     String
  completed Boolean
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

This is package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node .next/standalone/server.js",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

This is next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    experimental: {
        serverActions: true,
    },
    output: 'standalone',
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

page.tsx

```
import { TodoItem } from '@/components/TodoItem'
import { prisma } from '@/db'
import Link from 'next/link'

async function getTodos() {
  "use server"
  const res = await prisma.todos.findMany()
  console.log('returned res:', res)
  return res
}
async function toggleTodo(id: string, completed: boolean) {
  "use server"
  // console.log(id, completed)
  await prisma.todos.update({ where: { id }, data: { completed } })
}
export default async function Home() {
  const allTodos = await getTodos()

  // await prisma.todos.create({ data: { title: 'Get this to working', completed: false } }) //to add stuff to database
  return (
    <>
      <header className='flex justify-between items-center mb-4 p-8'>
        <h1 className='text-2xl'>ToDo&apos;s</h1>
        <Link href="/addToDo" className='border border-slate-300 text-slate-300 px-2 py-1 rounded hover:bg-slate-700 focus-within:bg-slate-700 outline-none'>Add ToDo</Link>

      </header>
      <ul className='pl-4'>
        {allTodos ? allTodos.map(todo => (
          <TodoItem key={todo.id} {...todo} toggleTodo={toggleTodo} />
        ))
          : null}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}
```

Thank you for all the help in advance.

Tried all different configurations for Prisma but all of them didn't work, this one is the closest to working version locally.

Comment: How does your connection string look?

Comment: A limit of 3 connections in a connection pool seems excessively low. An SqlConnectionPool in .NET, for example, has a limit of 100 connections/pool by default.

Comment: @siggemannen sqlserver://<ipAddress>:1633;database=nextjsDB;user=nextJS;password=***************;trustServerCertificate=true

Comment: 1633? that's weird, usually it's 1433

Comment: @AlwaysLearning i didn't change anything there just went with defaults

Comment: @siggemannen Yes agree, usually it's 1433, but that's what I got to connect and it's working locally so I used 1633. I pasted that to the string connection on the Azure portal under the variable name DATABASE_URL

Comment: @Pawel sir you don't have a special character in your password?, I always got an error of `Authentication fail to user` whenever I make a query but my connection string works when I do a db pull

Comment: @pryxen No I don't, but went through a special character issue before as well 